Which one of the solutions is correct: $f'(0) = undefined$ or $f'(0) = 3$?
$$f(x) = x(\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x+9})$$
$$f'(x) = x(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+9}}) + 1(\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x+9})$$
Now, to check whether $f(x)$ is differentiable or not, we evaluate $f'(x)$ for $x = 0$
For $1(\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x+9})$, we get 3
My query is in $x(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+9}})$ part, specifically $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$
--> Method 1:

We distribute $x^1$ over $x(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+9}})$ : $$x(\frac{x^1}{2\sqrt{x}} + \frac{x^1}{2\sqrt{x+9}})$$
In $\frac{x^1}{2\sqrt{x}}$, we take $\sqrt{x}$ in the numerator : $$\frac{x^1\times{x^\frac{-1}{2}}}{2}$$
This will give us $f'(0) = 3$ as answer

--> Method 2:

We distribute $x$ over $(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+9}})$: $$f'(x) = (\frac{x}{2\sqrt{x}} + \frac{x}{2\sqrt{x+9}}) + 1(\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x+9})$$
We place $x=0$ : $$f'(0) = (\frac{0}{2\sqrt{0}} + \frac{0}{2\sqrt{0+9}}) + 1(\sqrt{0} + \sqrt{0+9})$$
Now, $\frac{0}{2\sqrt{0}}$ is $undefined$
This will give us $f'(0) = undefined$

Is the solution for this is $f'(0) = undefined$ or $f'(0) = 3$?

You can use that $f$ is differentiable in $x_0$ iff $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f'(x)=\ell \in \mathbb{R}$

@SigmaAlgebra Can you please elaborate?

You can take only the right limit because the derivative exists only in $(0,+\infty)$

@SigmaAlgebra My main query is, which of the above methods is correct for solving $$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}$$

@SigmaAlgebra Got it, thanks for the help!

Wait a minute, $f'(0)$ it is not defined!

You can only tell that whenever $x\to 0^+$ the derivative approaches (from above) the value $3$, but the derivatives doesn't exists in $x=0$.

@SigmaAlgebra I have attached the image of the entire question. Can you please elaborate with respect to it?

Ok, I'll write the complete answer, give me a minute

Please try not to include images as part of your question.

@SigmaAlgebra Sure, I really appreciate it

Expanding on @Sigma Algebra’s comment. Because $f$ is only defined on $[0, \infty)$ our derivative is only defined on $(0,\infty)$. As stated in the comments, this is because we need the limit from both sides to exist.
However, you can consider $\lim_{x\to 0} f’(x)$. The simplest answer to this question would be to distribute the $x$ before you take the derivative. Your first method is correct but in the second method, you have to take the limit of that function as $x$ goes to 0. Because that is what we are concerned about when we say $f’(0)$.
So $f’(0)$ is not defined but $\lim_{x\to 0} f’(x)=3$

Isn't this a matter of convention? I've had some profs talk about differentiability at the endpoint of a closed interval ($0$ in this case) by simply taking the one-sided limit. Or perhaps just "by taking the limit", since the limit can be defined at any cluster point of the domain.

Yes, by convention I define the derivative of $f$ in the interior of the domain of $f$, and so I can only tell where the derivative approaches using the sided limits.  In this case, I don't even wonder what $f'(0)$ is

In that case, it depends on the intent of the person asking the question. Perhaps they allow for a function to be differentiable at potentially any cluster point.

Yes, it depends on the choice they made to define the derivative. Anyway, are you agree with me that with my def, that derivatives doesn't exists in $x=0$?

For most calculus level courses, it seems this is a question in a calculus course, the derivative needs to exist from both sides. But, I agree it definitely depends on the professor OP has and how they learned in their class.

Neither of your solutions is particularly well justified. There are two problems going on here.
1. You're trying to take a derivative at a point which is not an interior point of the domain.
The function $\sqrt{x}$ is only defined for $x \geq 0$, and usually, we only talk about differentiability at a point $a$ if $f(x)$ is defined in a neighborhood of $a$, which is not the case for $x=0$ here.
However, there is a notion of one-sided derivatives that we can apply, where we take the limit of $(f(a+h)-f(a))/h$ for $h \rightarrow 0^+$. I personally feel that this is the correct notion of differentiability at $x=0$ in this case, because it lets us make a meaningful difference between $x^{3/2}$, whose one-sided derivative at $0$ is $0$, and $\sqrt{x}$, whose one-sided derivative doesn't even exist - it approaches $\infty$. I'm sure there are also good reasons to not consider that $x^{3/2}$ is differentiable at $0$, but it comes down to a choice of convention.
So, let's suppose you want to ask about differentiability of your function $f(x)$ at $x=0$, even though the domain is $[0,\infty)$, by considering the one-sided limit. The sum and product rules still apply for one-sided limits (I'm pretty sure - someone please double-check me), so you could just take the derivative as you normally would, and get your answer. However, your problem still arises - there's something else going on.
2. You can't apply differentiation rules when the derivative doesn't exist.
You're trying to apply differentiation rules to find the (one-sided) derivative of $f$ at $0$, but $f$ is defined using the function $\sqrt{x}$, which is not differentiable (even in a one-sided way) at $x=0$.
For instance, the "derivative of a sum" rule states that if $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ are differentiable at $a$, then $f(x) = g(x) + h(x)$ is differentiable at $a$ and is given by $f'(a) = g'(a) + h'(a)$. When you take the derivative of $\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x+9}$, you're applying this rule, which is fine as long as $x>0$, because both functions are differentiable on that domain. However, at $x=0$, $\sqrt{x}$ is not differentiable (the one-sided limit approaches $\infty$), so you can no longer conclude that $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x+9}$ is differentiable at $0$.
Now, this isn't necessarily a dealbreaker - for example, the function $|x|$ isn't differentiable at $0$, but the sum $|x| + (-|x|) = 0$ is differentiable - but you have to be more careful in your analysis. In particular, what you need to do is simplify your function. Indeed, for any $x \geq 0$, you have
$$
f(x) = x\sqrt{x} + x\sqrt{x+9} = x^{3/2} + x\sqrt{x+9}.
$$
Finally, you can apply your rules correctly. The derivative of $x^{3/2}$ is $(3/2)\sqrt{x}$, and this formula is valid on $[0,\infty)$ if we consider the derivative at $0$ to be one-sided. The function $x\sqrt{x+9}$ is differentiable on $[0,\infty)$ (there is no problem here), so you get $f'(x) = (3/2)\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x+9} + x/2\sqrt{x+9}$ for $x \geq 0$, and you can safely plug in $x=0$ to get $f'(0) = 3$.
In short:
There are two possibilities here. If you don't allow derivatives at endpoints of closed intervals, then your function isn't differentiable at $x=0$ by definition, since its domain is $[0,\infty)$.
However, if you do allow derivatives at endpoints of closed intervals by taking the one-sided limit, then we find $f'(0)=3$ by first simplifying $f(x)$ before differentiating. Your approach wasn't well justified because you tried to apply differentiation rules when one of the derivatives wasn't defined (the derivative of $\sqrt{x}$ at $x=0$).

Let $f(x)=x(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x+9})$.
It's clearly continuous in $[0,+\infty)$ (the entire domain) because is product and sum of continuous functions in $[0,+\infty)$ (you also can easily check the limits)
For the differentiability, holds what @Nic says. So, the derivative doesn't exist in $x=0$.
Therefore, the correct answer is $B$.

Would the correct answer not be D. In your answer, you implied that $f$ is not continuous at 0.

Oh yes, you're right. I've typed wrong the brackets. Correct it!

But again, we reach the issue that a function needs a neighborhood around each point to be continuous. With no full neighborhood around 0, I would not consider this function continuous at 0.

Well, we could settle for a right neighborhood. In fact, if $x\to 0^+$ the function approaches $0$ without jumps, and $f(0)=0$.

Yeah, it’s this ambiguity that irks me about multiple choice questions like this.

For the continuity we can also be satisfied only with the limits on the sides, for the differentiability we define the derivative only within the continuity domain of $f$. For extreme cases, we can tell what happens only by taking the lateral limits of the derivative, if it is continuous in at least one lateral neighborhood of the extremal point. I think that it's the most useful way to do exercises. But obviously, if you study within a course, you must trust how your teacher defines the things.

@Nic Continuity at a point $a$ never requires $a$ to be an interior point of the domain. Speaking generally, a neighborhood of $a$ is an open subset of the domain (with respect to the topology of the domain) which contains $a$. In the case of $[0,\infty)$, which is equipped with the subspace topology, neighborhoods of $0$ are of the form $[0,\epsilon)$.

If you want to know if the function $\,f(x)=x(\sqrt x\!+\!\sqrt{x+9})\,$ is differentiable at $\,x=0\,$ and evaluate $\,f’(0)\,$ in the case that it exists, you could proceed by using the definition of derivative of a function at a point.
$\begin{align}f’(0)&=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{x(\sqrt x+\sqrt{x+9})-0}{x-0}=\\[3pt]&=\lim\limits_{x\to0}(\sqrt x+\sqrt{x+9})=\sqrt9=3\,.\end{align}$
Hence, the function $\,f(x)\,$ is differentiable at $\,x=0\,$ and $\,f’(0)=3\,.$
